# Is there a way to upload/edit files from Android to LittleFS

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I am using ArduinoDroid to program ESP8266 every day on my way to work but the huge hindrance is my inability to upload HTML, JS and CSS files to LittleFS from android phone, I cannot find the way to access LittleFS from Android, can someone point me to the software capable of doing this?